# How to connect CSS and JS to Chromium Delphi locally?

Tags: javascript, html, css, delphi, web-applications

there is a website on wordpress, i load it through TChromium in project Delphi.how to make loading files: css, js, images locally? if the files lie near to exe.

and another question is why TChromium not playing video?
on youtube works, the with video direct link not load(

Answer (score 2):

You can load local files by loading a FILE URL. In case of [DCEF3](https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3) you would call *TChromium.Load* and in case of [CEF4Delphi](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi) or [OldCEF4Delphi](https://github.com/salvadordf/OldCEF4Delphi) you would call *TChromium.LoadURL*.

The FILE URL would look like this :
file:///c:/path/file.html

Read these pages to know more about FILE URLs :
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8089
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

The HTML and CSS files would have to use relative paths to the other resources or the browser will not find them.

Chromium has some security limitations for local files. If you find any issue loading your files with a FILE URL then you could try to load them with a custom URL scheme. CEF4Delphi has a demo called [SchemeRegistrationBrowser](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi/tree/master/demos/SchemeRegistrationBrowser) that shows you how to register a custom scheme.

About the issue with the videos, it's a codec problem. The CEF3 binaries available at Spotify only have the open source codecs enabled due to patent restrictions.

If you need to watch H264 videos then you need to build the CEF3 binaries following these instructions :
http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=13515

Edit : I forgot that some video players require Flash. Install the PPAPI Adobe Flash Player from here : https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/
CEF4Delphi enables the flash player by default but you might need to use the *--enable-system-flash* command switch with DCEF3.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know where to download the CEF3 binaries with proprietary codec support enabled.